# data as variable name pointer js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to use date-attribute to store the name of the variable existing in my js. So button click get the name and give it to the function

```
var total_tax_t_data_portal_month_sum = [123123]



$(".chart_update").on("click", function () {
                    console.log($(this).data("chart-id"));
                    console.log($(this).data("chart-data"));
                    console.log($(this).data("chart-lable"));

                    self = this;
                    updateBarGraph($(this).data("chart-id"), $(this).data("chart-data"), $(this).data("chart-lable"))

                });
```

This is my html

```
<span class="dropdown-item chart_update" href="#" data-chart-id="tax_dash_portal" data-chart-data="total_tax_t_data_portal_month_sum" data-chart-lable="n_month_name" >This Month</span>

<canvas id="tax_dash_portal" class="mt-4" height="200px"></canvas>
```

my good works when I get the names like this but not when get them from the date-attribute which I won't to use to update my chart.js with out needing to hare code can this work.

```
updateBarGraph(tax_dash_portal, n_month_name, total_tax_t_data_portal_month_sum)
```

### edit

```
                 function updateBarGraph(chart, label, data) {
                        self = this;
                        console.log(chart);
                        chart.data.datasets.pop();
                        chart.data.labels.length = 0;
                        chart.data.labels.push(label);
    
                        chart.data.datasets.push({
                            label: label,
                            backgroundColor: gradientFill,
                            data: data
                        });
                        chart.update();
                    }
```

Comment: How specifically is the code failing?

Comment: I am going `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'chart.data.datasets')`@David

Comment: What line in your code produces that error?  Is it coming from within `updateBarGraph()`?  What is that function and what does it do with the values you give it?  When you debug, are those values what you expect them to be?

Comment: @David I added the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This results in a string value:

```
$(this).data("chart-id")
```

Which you're sending to the function and then trying to use it as an object:

```
chart.data.datasets.pop();
```

A string containing a variable name is not a variable.  You *can* use a string to get that variable (more specifically, that reference), if you know where that variable is scoped.  For example, if it's on the `window` object (in global scope) then you can use the string to reference it:

```
window[$(this).data("chart-id")]
```

If it's not in `window` scope and is local to a function, you may want to store it and other variables referenced in this manner in an object of some kind.  Any object can use the same syntax that's being used on `window` above.  For example, suppose you have this object:

```
var myObj = {
    someProperty: 1
};
```

Then you can reference the property based on a string like this:

```
myObj['someProperty']
```

Comment: my code in inside a .then() function so can I use window
is there a better way of doing what I am doing

Comment: @MoazMabrok: Possibly, but I can't know without seeing a more complete example.  However you do it, the concept is always the same.  If you have a string which contains the name of the variable you want to reference, you can use that string on an indexer for an object whos property is that variable. JavaScript can get a little confusing in this regard, because globally-scoped variables are automatically part of the `window` object but function-scope variables are not part of any object. So if your variable is local to a function then make it a property on an object instead of its own variable.

Comment: @MoazMabrok: That depends entirely on where your `tax_dash_portal` variable is scoped.  If it's on the `window` then you'd use `window[$(this).data("chart-id")]`.  If it's on `document` then try `document[$(this).data("chart-id")]`.  If it's neither then you might need to add it to one of those.  For example, just before calling your function you can try `window.tax_dash_portal = tax_dash_portal;` and then use `window[$(this).data("chart-id")]`